# Disable a Sublime key-binding entirely?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I want to get rid of these completely:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+up"], "command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": 1.0 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+down"], "command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": -1.0 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+up"], "command": "swap_line_up" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+down"], "command": "swap_line_down" },
```

Just have those keys do nothing.

So I copied them into my default user bindings and then... what?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit**: if you want to prevent Sublime from capturing the keyboard shortcut completely, instead of just getting Sublime to do nothing when you use the shortcut, see J Spen's answer below.

Owen_R's solution does not work in Sublime 3; instead of `false`, just put a command that does not exist:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+up"],          "command": "pass" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+down"],        "command": "pass" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+up"],    "command": "pass" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+down"],  "command": "pass" },
```

I know this post is old and you asked specifically for ST2, but since this post still appears in the first results on most search engines, I think it will help people to find ST3's solution here too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still using ST2, but I started just binding things to `"do_nothing"` a while ago... until the notification email from your here answer, I forgot I even ever used to use the `false` thing.

Comment: This disables them in ST3, but it insists on continuing to override the OS's keybindings for this NOP action.  Therefore commands like Ctrl+Optn+Left/Right to move windows around are blocked by ST3.  Any idea on how to force ST3 to play nicely?

Comment: J Spen's answer below is the solution.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to bind something like `ctrl+l` to other things using `ctrl+l w` for example then disabling it won't work because will completely disable the use of `ctrl+l` for complex bindings as well. You have to install package: `PackageResourceViewer` and then using the command palette in sublime after installing use `open Resource` from that package and navigate to `Default/Default (Your OS).sublime-keymap`. Then comment out the lines in this file of the bindings you don't want. This won't override them but just permanently remove them as defaults so other packages can set and use them so depends your desired outcome.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want hotkeys from an external application such as Spectacle on macOS to work properly.

Comment: This is the correct answer for stopping Sublime Text 3 from taking over OS control for OS shortcuts like moving windows around. (Simply marking as "false" or "pass" makes them NOPs, but they still take control over the OS.)

Comment: @JasonDoucette I 100% agree! I remember this took me awhile to figure out, but feel free to give an up vote.

Comment: This is incorrect. You shouldn't change the default files, because they will get overwritten when updating the app.

Comment: Default/Default macOS.sublime-keymap isn't one of the options in 'open Resource'.

Comment: Let me just say this is a highly intelligent answer. @ErikaElectra once you select "open Resource" think of what it's showing you as a directory listing ie. select "Default" then select "Default macOS.sublime-keymap".

Answer (score 5):

Oh, it's just:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+up"],          "command": false },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+down"],        "command": false },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+up"],    "command": false },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+down"],  "command": false },
```