# Sublime Text 3 remove default keyboard shortcut

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I find no way to unset or remove default keyboard shortcuts in Sublime Text 3. The default settings are not editable anymore, so I have this in there:

```
{ "keys": ["f2"], "command": "next_bookmark" },
```

I have tried `"command": "unbound"` in user settings but it just unbinds the "next_bookmark" command from it, the key is still intercepted and captured by ST3. I have some important global shortcuts which I'm simply unable to use without switching to another window first.

Is there any way of solving this?

Comment: copy the default keyboard shortcut settings into the user keyboard settings and edit there.

Answer (score 5):

You can override the default package. To do this easily, you can use https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer. Open the `Default/Default (your os).sublime-keymap` file, make your edits, then save the file. The plugin will place it in the proper location to override the default bundled file.

Comment: A word of comment: after doing so, the `PackageResourceView` will put the extracted package in a writable status. To restore the default keymap settings back into a read-only status, use `chmod u-w Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`, for example (on Mac).

Comment: Note: this also works with shortcuts added by other packages in the same way you can override their sublime-keymap files.

Answer (score 1):

To insert Unicode in Ubuntu 18.04 I normally use ctrl+shift+u, but that fails in ST3.

I can't find any method that works on ST3 3175 under Ubuntu. I tried mapping it to "pass", to false, and using Package Resource Viewer to edit file .../Packages/Keymaps/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap.

There is a package ([Unicode Character Insert](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Unicode%20Character%20Insert)) that says it will insert unicode characters but it only puts up a small chart of characters it knows about.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very old, but I found the solution that worked for me with no packages installed [here](https://superuser.com/a/1029886/265896).

All you have to do is use the same default setting in the user defined part with replacing the command with "pass".